# delphi string to handle type casting

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, lazarus

Is there anyway to safely convert/typecast a string inside TEdit (an actual window handle for eg. 00010C10) into a handle LONGWORD data type I presume in Delphi/Lazarus.

Recommended method here [Pascal - String to LongWord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13142037/pascal-string-to-longword) is IntToStr but compiler throws following error:

Exception class EConvertError with message '00010C10' is not a valid integer value

Also tried IntToStr64 but no luck....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because by default the [`StrToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt) expects the string to be in decimal notation. To convert an hex notation string to integer prefix it with `$`, ie

```
intVal := StrToInt('$'+Edit1.Text);
```